# shell parsing json contains spaces in string

Tags: json, shell, sed, grep

I need to parse json which contains spaces in string in it, but the output value is truncated at spaces.

My `Initial.json` file is:

```
{
  "WorkspaceName":"aaa bbb ccc ddd eee",
  "ReportFileName":"xxx yyy zzz",
  "StageName":"sit uat prod"
}
```

My current shell code is:

```
InitialFile=$JsonPath/deployment/configuration/Initial.json
data=$(cat $InitialFile | sed -r 's/",/"/' | egrep -v '^[{}]' | sed 's/"//g' | sed 's/:/=/1')
declare $data

echo WorkspaceName is_$WorkspaceName
echo ReportFileName is_$ReportFileName
echo StageName is_$StageName
```

The result is:

```
WorkspaceName is_aaa

ReportFileName is_xxx 

StageName is_sit
```

The expected reuslt is `aaa bbb ccc ddd eee`, `xxx yyy zzz`, `sit uat prod` instead of `aaa`, `xxx`, `sit`.

How to achieve it? I'm not very familiar with shells, any advice would be greatly appreciated.

**Update:**

I using following code to resolve this issue:

```
WorkspaceName=$(grep -o '"WorkspaceName": "[^"]*' configuration/Initial.json | grep -o '[^"]*$')
ReportFileName=$(grep -o '"ReportFileName": "[^"]*' configuration/Initial.json | grep -o '[^"]*$')
StageName=$(grep -o '"StageName": "[^"]*' configuration/Initial.json | grep -o '[^"]*$')
```

As you can see, this solves the problem, but it doesn't seem perfect, I need to get each variable in the json separately, there will be a lot of repeated statements, when there are many variables in the json, this will be a Very troublesome, **so is there a way to simplify it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use sed and regexp:

```
eval $(sed -n -e 's/^.*"\(.*\)":\(".*"\).*$/\1=\2/p' $InitialFile)
```

- `sed` will take the filename as an argument
- `-n` will make sed not print per default
- `-e 's/<match pattern>/<output>/` a sed command to search and replace ([live test](https://sed.js.org/?gist=cdc2e7dfc0ba4cbb92de87eebc7dfe75)).
- `p` in case of matching pattern the output is printed
- `eval` will evaluate the output as if you would have written it at the prompt. In this case assigning values to some vars.

I think the code above is shorter and better in several ways, but it could of course be done your way with some adjustment, or in several other ways. The main issue with your code is that the assignment needs to be one string, not several. So your code produces this:

```
WorkspaceName=aaa bbb ccc ddd eee
```

while it should be:

```
WorkspaceName="aaa bbb ccc ddd eee"
```

Comment: My code produce is `aaa` not `aaa bbb ccc ddd eee`, `aaa bbb ccc ddd eee` is what I want to get.

Comment: And I using another way to resolve this question, I will update the question.

Comment: The solution I provided will do assignment automatically for all variables in the json-data just as you asked for in your edit.

Comment: OK, how do I to get each value by using the variable like `$WorkspaceName`

Comment: And your comment _My code produce is aaa not ..._ is wrong! The row in you code `data=$(cat ...)` will produce rows like `WorkspaceName=aaa bbb ccc ddd eee` and that assignment will be interpreted as `WorkspaceName=aaa` since you need to wrap your string as `"string including whitespace"`.

Comment: Replace row 2 and 3 of your initial code example (the `data=...` and `declare...` rows) with my one row and all will be done!

Comment: @U, Do you have time to help me check my another thread? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74135432/shell-parsing-json-and-loop-output-the-combine-variable Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

***1st solution(GNU `awk`):*** With GNU `awk` you can try following solution, written and tested with your shown samples only.

```bash
awk -v RS='"[^"]*":"[^"]*",?' '
RT{
  sub(/":"/,OFS,RT)
  gsub(/^"|",?$/,"",RT)
  print RT
}
' Input_file
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** If `jq` is allowed you can simply do following command. Which OP is saying is not in OP's system but adding it as a variant here.

```bash
jq -r 'to_entries[] | "\(.key) \(.value)"' Input_file
```

With shown samples output will be as follows:

```
WorkspaceName aaa bbb ccc ddd eee
ReportFileName xxx yyy zzz
StageName sit uat prod
```

Comment: Sorry, I not sure I could use jq. That is because I check it and found it not installed in my server. If I use jq, I need install it before we using it.

Comment: @Joy, Sure give it a shot to install if you could, this is best tool for json parsing, if you can't install it then we can go for other tools eg: `sed`, `awk`, `grep` OR `perl`. I will also add another non jq solution in a min or so.

Comment: @Joy, I have added an `awk` solution now, kindly do check it once and let me know how it goes, cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed`

```
$ InitialFile="${JsonPath}/deployment/configuration/Initial.json"
$ data=$(sed -En 's/^[^"]*"([^"]*)":"([^"]*).*$/\1 is_\2/p' "$InitialFile")
$ echo "$data"
WorkspaceName is_aaa bbb ccc ddd eee
ReportFileName is_xxx yyy zzz
StageName is_sit uat prod
```

Comment: The output is null, echo ''

Comment: @Joy Is the InitialFile source correct? If so, the output should be as the output I have provided.

Comment: I double check it and it indeed output all the values, but how to get each value? like, I want use `$WorkspaceName ` to get the value `aaa bbb ccc ddd eee`

Comment: @Joy WorkspaceName=$(sed -En '/WorkspaceName/s/^[^"]*"([^"]*)":"([^"]*).*$/\1 is_\2/p' "$InitialFile") and so on

Comment: hm, this solution will have the same follow-up problem, as the solution I mentioned in the question, when there are many variables, then the code will be redundant

Comment: Indeed, hence why I totally skipped creating multiple variables and instead provided the expected output.
I think you will need to elaborate a bit more exactly what you are trying to achieve and the problems faced in the question @Joy

Comment: @HatLess, When I run this code it worked fine for me.