# shell parsing json and loop output the combine variable

Tags: json, shell, awk, sed, grep

Jusk like [my previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74063588/shell-parsing-json-contains-spaces-in-string), I know how to parse simple json with spaces.

Now I have another question is that if I have multiple module structures, their keys are the same, but the values are different, **I want the output value to be a combination of the values in each module, but actually the value in the last module will overwrite the previous one.**

My test sample JSON like:

```json
{
  "WorkspaceName":"aaa bbb ccc ddd eee",
  "ReportFileName":"xxx yyy zzz",
  "StageName":"sit uat prod"
},
{
  "WorkspaceName":"1111 2222 3333 4444 5555",
  "ReportFileName":"6666 7777 8888",
  "StageName":"sit1 uat1 prod1"
}
```

And my tried shell script(s) `mian.sh` is as follows:

```
InitialFile=$WORKSPACE/deployment/configuration/Initial.json
eval $(sed -n -e 's/^.*"\(.*\)":\(".*"\).*$/\1=\2/p' $InitialFile)

ConfigFile="$WorkspaceName"_"$ReportFileName"

echo The Config File is_$ConfigFile
```

The result is always `The Config File is_1111 2222 3333 4444 5555_6666 7777 8888`, I want get both  values: `aaa bbb ccc ddd eee_xxx yyy zzz` and `1111 2222 3333 4444 5555_6666 7777 8888`.

How do I achieve this?

A little **background** to understand why I'm doing this and some of my limitations：

I am executing my pipeline on jenkins and it will execute my mian.sh. So the entry is mian.sh. In addition, the jenkins server is maintained by a separate team, and we cannot directly access the server, so we cannot run shell code directly on the server.

Another, I need to combine variables in order to use this variable to match the name of the corresponding configuration file. Different results need to match different files for subsequent testing.

Comment: Experts always advice to use tools like `jq` which understand json file well. Can you use jq here? Once you confirm you may get answer as per that, cheers.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, Thanks for your comment, I could not allowed to use jq, because the security level of our server is relatively high. We cannot install jq. It cannot be installed until the end. If the installation is unavoidable, and the installation will to be a very long process of security approval and verification

Comment: Ok sure, thanks for confirming, have added an answer based on that, cheers.

Comment: IMHO the usage of `eval` will rather increase the security risk.

Comment: There are other tools that are commonly available on servers and also understand JSON, e.g. Python. This is going to be extremely flaky without a proper JSON parser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Important points for this answer:***

- Since OP can't install and use `jq` so going with an `awk` approach here.
- I have provided 3 solutions here, **1st:** is GNU `awk` approach and **2nd** is NON-GNU `awk` approach and **3rd** one is running NON-GNU `awk` code from a shell script.
- 1st 2 codes are stand along `awk` codes to run on terminal OR in an `awk` script
- Then as per OP's request since their code is running in `Jenkins` I have posted a shell script which accepts an argument which is a Input_file name to be passed to it.
- To save output into a shell variable could be done in 3rd code of this answer by changing 1st line to `StageName=$(awk -v RS= '` **and** changing last line of 3rd code to `'  "$1")`.

---

***1st solution:*** With your shown samples please try following **GNU** `awk` code. Using `match` function of GNU `awk` where I am using regex `[[:space:]]+"WorkspaceName":"([^"]*)",\n[[:space:]]+"ReportFileName":"([^"]*)` to get the required values and creating 2 capturing groups out of it which further stores values into an array named `arr` to be get values later on as pre reuiqrement.

```
awk -v RS= '
{
  while(match($0,/[[:space:]]+"WorkspaceName":"([^"]*)",\n[[:space:]]+"ReportFileName":"([^"]*)",/,arr)){
    print arr[1]"_"arr[2]
    $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
  }
}
'  Input_file
```

***2nd solution:*** With your shown samples please try following code, should work in any POSIX awk. This solution also uses `match` function but it doesn't create array and doesn't have any capturing groups in it, since capturing group capability is part of GNU `awk`. So using `split` function here to split the matched values and get only required part out of it.

```
awk -v RS= '
{
  while(match($0,/[[:space:]]+"WorkspaceName":"[^"]*",\n[[:space:]]+"ReportFileName":"[^"]*",/)){
    val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
    split(val,arr,"\"WorkspaceName\":\"|\"ReportFileName\":\"|,\n")
    sub(/"$/,"",arr[2])
    sub(/",$/,"",arr[4])
    print arr[2]"_"arr[4]
    $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
  }
}
'  Input_file
```

---

---

***To run code from shell script try like:***

```
#!/bin/bash
awk -v RS= '
{
  while(match($0,/[[:space:]]+"WorkspaceName":"[^"]*",\n[[:space:]]+"ReportFileName":"[^"]*",/)){
    val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
    split(val,arr,"\"WorkspaceName\":\"|\"ReportFileName\":\"|,\n")
    sub(/"$/,"",arr[2])
    sub(/",$/,"",arr[4])
    print arr[2]"_"arr[4]
    $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
  }
}
'  "$1"
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. What preconditions do I need to use GNU awk, can other tools be installed via commands and do I need admin rights? I can only access our server as a guest account and cannot directly remote the server. We just deploy the jenkins agent on the server. We can only use the agent, not the server directly

Comment: @Joy, If you are not having access to install GNU `awk` then you could request your root admins(yes we need root access OR sudo access given by root admins to install something) who have access(as per your company's process) and if it will take time then try my **2nd** solution which doesn't need GNU `awk` and let me know how it goes, cheers.

Comment: Sure, I will. By the way,  how did I get the value of `ConfigFile` by using your second solution. Sorry for the simple question as I'm not very familiar with shells.

Comment: @Joy, You can pass your Input_file to this `awk` program and it will print the values then let me know what further is required out of it, we can do it.

Comment: @Joy, If you need to concatenate all values and save it into variable we can easily do it, once you confirm about running command on Input_file I can take care of it then.

Comment: If I understand you correct, I need to run above code in the server with POSIX awk, and it will ask me to input the json file？Am I right? If yes, I am afraid I could not do it, because I could not access the server directly by remoting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248921/discussion-between-joy-and-ravindersingh13).

Comment: @Joy, how are you passing input to program then? And are you not running program where your file is present? Sorry I didn't get it. Its simple this will work in any `awk` just run this code on *NIX terminal and pass file to it(change Input_file name in my code to your actual file's name).

Comment: I could not run the code on the NIX terminal. I am working on the jenkins, It will invoke my main.sh file, and I parse the json file in it and conbine the variable as new variable, that is reason why I define json file in the mian.sh like `InitialFile=$WORKSPACE/deployment/configuration/Initial.json`. Jenkins does not exeute the pipeline in interactive mode. So, I could not do that as you suggest.

Comment: @Joy, Please don't update the question, kindly revert it back to original one as it will have multiple questions in it. For jenkins thing we can discuss here, revert it and let me know then. Once we find solution we can update Q & A both so that users are not confused IMHO.

Comment: @Joy, How are you running your current tried code? kindly do let me know.

Comment: Sure, I revert it back. Current I execute the mian.sh by jenkins. It will execute the main.sh by the built-in shell task.

Comment: @Joy, I have now updated my answer check section `To run code from shell script try like:` and save whole content into your script. This script assumes that you are passing file name as parameter to it, because that's how your current setup running I believe so, in my code `"$1"` stand for 1st argument value only.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think we are close to the answer. As I test, I pass `"$InitialFile"` instead of `1`, And the result output two value: `aaa bbb ccc ddd eee xxx yyy zzz` and `1111 2222 3333 4444 5555 6666 7777 8888`. A little help is that 1. WorkspaceName and ReportFileName are joined together by underscore. 2. How do I assign a value to a variable so that I can use it to loop through it. 3. How to get StageName?

Comment: @Joy, So you need output with a join of `_`? Sorry I didn't get it fully.

Comment: Yes, I use it to match my files, my files are named like this `aaa bbb ccc ddd eee_xxx yyy zzz.json`. This helps me to know the WorkspaceName and ReportFileName. If spaces are used, it's hard to see them because they themselves contain spaces

Comment: @Joy, so you need output from script like `aaa bbb ccc ddd eee_xxx yyy zzz_1111 2222 3333 4444 5555_6666 7777 8888`? Please confirm once.

Comment: Not accurate, what I need is `aaa bbb ccc ddd eee_xxx yyy zzz`  and `1111 2222 3333 4444 5555_6666 7777 8888`. The output should be 2 values, then I need to loop over each value

Comment: @Joy, its giving you 2 values as of now correct? If yes then please explain what's the problem by which you are not able to retrieve both?

Comment: Yes, I got 2 values. But missing the `_` between WorkspaceName and ReportFileName. For example, the actual: `aaa bbb ccc ddd eee xxx yyy zzz`, Expect is `aaa bbb ccc ddd eee_xxx yyy zzz`. And the other two questions is 2. How do I assign a value to a variable so that I can use it to loop through it. 3. How to get StageName?

Comment: The combination of WorkspaceName and ReportFileName is the name of a file, then there are multiple sets of WorkspaceName and ReportFileName in the json, then what I want is that each set of WorkspaceName and ReportFileName forms a different file name, so that I can match different file names. This way I can call the same function and get different results depending on the file passed

Comment: @Joy, I am Sorry not able to understand, could you please explain how output should look? Also I am having lunch but will reply from mobile

Comment: no worries. You can enjoy your lunch without rushing it. I will wait. Now the output result is `workspaceName ReportFileName`, they are concatenated by **space**, but I want to concatenate by **underscore**, like `workspaceName_ReportFileName`.

Comment: @Joy, I have edited code now, I think I get it now and edited code. Please do check and let me know how it goes.

Comment: Cheers! Now, it output the expected values. Now, I want to assign those values to a variable and I also want to get the variable `StageName`. Would you please kindly help me this? Thanks.

Comment: @Joy, do it like: change line `awk -v RS= '` **to** `StageName=$(awk -v RS= '` and then change last line of code `'  "$1"` **to** `'  "$1")`, basically creating shell variable and closing it, cheers.

Comment: @Joy, Great that it worked for you, I have put back your changes in question with all details, cheers and keep posting Good questions and answers on this great site.